# How to split a string vector by comma and convert to data frame in R Statistical Programming

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a string vector in R like this 
     c('a,b,c,d','c,d,e','d,c','a,b,d')
I have to convert it to a Data frame as given below.
Note that strings could be off different lengths. So here in 3rd row after d & c there should be blanks under columns 3 & 4

```
a b c d
c d e   
d c     
a b d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the test input in the Note at the end.

```
read.table(text = x, sep = ",", fill = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  a  b  c  d
2  c  d  e   
3  d  c      
4  a  b  d
```

### Note

Test input

```
x <- c('a,b,c,d','c,d,e','d,c','a,b,d')
```

Comment: Thanks. This is great.

Answer (score 3):

We split by the `,` into a `list`, append `NA` at the end for those having less elements and convert to `data.frame`

```
lst <- strsplit(v1, ",")
out <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
colnames(out) <- paste0("V", seq_along(out))
out <- sapply(out, as.character)
out[is.na(out)] <- ""
out
```

Comment: ...The Oracle was summoned

Comment: What is the use of `length<-` here ?

Comment: @YOLO  Suppose you have a vector `a <- 1:3` and you want to have the length 5, then `length(a) <- 5`.  It will append 2 NAs at the end.  In this case, we already have a `list` object ('lst') and the `length<-` assignment is for maximum length of the list where lengths give you the individual length of each list element

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple. use below

```
test <- c('a,b,c,d','c,d,e','d,c','a,b,d')
data_frame <- data.frame(test)
data_frame
```

Comment: the answer is to what is asked by the user